# My Service is not stopped

Tags: android, service

I am new to services. I've started service by using AlaramManager. It will work fine but when I try to stop service it does not stop service.

method for start service

```
        Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent intent = new Intent(XoroActivity.this, XorService.class);
         pintent = PendingIntent.getService(XoroActivity.this,
                0, intent, 0);
         alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mStarted = true;
        if (mB_IntervalStr.equals("1 minute")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        } else if (mB_IntervalStr.equals("2 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 2 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        } else if (mB_IntervalStr.equals("5 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        } else if (mB_IntervalStr.equals("10 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        } else if (mB_IntervalStr.equals("30 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        } else if (mB_IntervalStr.equals("60 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
```

method for stop service

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.teks.xormobile", "com.teks.xormobile.XorService");
        stopService(i);
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
```

It does not work. Please give me a solution to how to stop service....

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are trying to stop the service from within itself. You maybe interested in using `stopSelf()` method then..

Comment: Ok.Know it's fine It's work me.My service is stop.                                                                    I am just create alarm object and pending intent object                  pintent = PendingIntent.getService(XoroActivity.this,
                0, i, 0);
         alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);